# If a function $f$ has the intermediate value property show that it has no discontinuity of first kind

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

> If a function $f:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R $ has the intermediate value property show that it has no removable discontinuity or discontinuity of first kind.

Suppose $f$ has discontinuity of first kind say at $c$ .Then $f(c+),f(c-)$ both exist but are not equal.

But how to arrive at a contradiction from here?Please help.

Comment: For $x$ close enough to $c$ (but distinct), $f(x)$ will be close to either $f(c+)$ or $f(c-)$, so it won't attain values strictly between these two.

Comment: The definition of $f(c^+)$ is $$\lim_{x\to c^+} f(x)=\text{the number }\ell\text{ s. t. }\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta>0, \forall x\in(c,c+\delta),\ \left\lvert f(x)-\ell\right\rvert<\varepsilon$$ what can you therefore say of $f(x)$ for $x>c$ and $x-c$ sufficiently small? Is then $f(c^-)\ne f(c^+)$ consistent with IVT?

Comment: For the other case, you can recycle the same argument.